# Civicrm Wordpress 5.44 install fails with critical error on this website

Tags: wordpress

Hoping for some help.

Hostgator: Shared
CMS: Wordpress 5.8.2 fresh install. All Plugins deactivated and deleted to start with
PHP: 7.4.26
Mysql: 5.6
OS: Centos 6 release 94.0.19
Memory Limit increased to 256MB
[accountname] has replaced the actual account name

After downloading Cvicrm 5.44 and loading into a fresh install of WP, when trying to Wp->Activate

It shows me where the civicrm tables will be installed.  I click the green INSTALL button and almost immediately I see
“There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.  I checked. There is no email for instructions.

When I look at the mysql db created for WP, other than the WP tables, it shows 1 table created, civicrm_address_format with 2 fields, ID and format.

From the Install Screen:

Environment
The system settings were auto-detected. CiviCRM will be installed with:
CMS Database
mysql://[accountname]_wp735:HIDDEN@localhost/[accountname]_wp735
CiviCRM Database
mysql://[accountname]_wp735:HIDDEN@localhost/[accountname]_wp735 
CiviCRM Settings File
/home2/[accountname]/public_html/ncrm/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php
CiviCRM Source Code
/home2/[accountname]/public_html/ncrm/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm

I checked the civicrm.settings.php - that has the username/password for the db usernme/password and since the address format table was created, I assume that the install has appropriate access and permissions to create tables.

Once it fails, when I try to do anything within WP I get this Initialization Error.  If I rename the plugins civicrm to something else, I can again access the WP admin dashboard.

If the "civicrm" folder is contained within the wp-content/plugins after the failed install, I get this error each time I try to do anything in WP.

Initialization Error

Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => simpleHandler
)

```
[code] => -18
[message] => DB Error: no such table
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
```

FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
[nativecode=1146 ** Table '[accountname]_wp735.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
[nativecode=1146 ** Table '[accountname]_wp735.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such table" code=-18 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::simpleHandler prefix="" info="SELECT id, name, value, domain_id, contact_id, is_domain, component_id, created_date, created_id
FROM civicrm_setting
WHERE (domain_id = 1) AND (is_domain = 1)
[nativecode=1146 ** Table '[accountname]_wp735.civicrm_setting' doesn't exist]"]

How can I further troubleshoot?

Comment: My first suggestion is always to contact your host. These errors are often times related to a missing requirement on your server or a rule that needs to be whitelisted. Pretty much every time I get it, it ends up being something I need the host's help to accomplish. They should be able to look at the server logs and give you more info.

Comment: Thanks for that info Jenni.  I started out figuring the same thing, and they said they didn't "see" anything, so let me ask you, which log should they be looking at?  When civicrm gives me the screen with the green install button, the only requirements message is for the multi-lingual environment which I don't need.  The message says it's not required so I didn't install it.

Comment: Requirements like the version of PHP and such. If everything shows as green, it should be ok, though. But things like the amount of memory and such aren't tested there. My host looks at the server log, as it should show an error at the time you tried to do it. For me it's almost always been a security issue where they needed to whitelist something.

Comment: So I see that my environment is running mysql 5.6 and the requirements call for 5.7 so that is probably the issue.  I'll have to see what can be done about that.